# Tabla temporal SQL SERVER a CURSOR en PL-SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Saludos

¿ Como podría transformar el uso de una tabla temporal para hacer un update en SQL server a un código equivalente en PLSQL con un cursor ?

```
            ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_lista] (@pcFI datetime, @pcFF datetime, @vSuma tinyint) as
    begin tran

    Declare @crLista Table (
          NEnt int,
          NEje int,
          NExp char(17),
          NAcu char(17),
          NSen char(17)
     )

     if @vSuma = 0
                  begin
                       insert into @crLista 
                       select tablax.num_entrada, tablax.ejercicio,                                               tablax.num_expediente, tablax.num_acuerdo, tablax.num_sentencia,    tablax.descripcion
from tablax inner join tablaz on
tablaz.num_expediente = tablax.num_expediente
where tablax.est_suma = 0 and (EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM tablay
  WHERE tablay.cve_usuario = SESSION_USER
  and tablay.cve_region = tablaz.cve_region
  and tablay.cve_sala = tablaz.cve_sala
  and tablay.cve_mag = tablaz.cve_mag
  and tablay.cve_srio = tablaz.cve_srio))


    update tablax 
     set notificado = 1,
     fec_notificado = getdate()
     from @crLista MLista
     where MLista.NEnt = tablax.num_entrada and
     MLista.NEje = tablax.ejercicio and tablax.est_suma = @vSuma
```

En PL-SQL Tengo algo como lo que sigue:

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE sp_lista(
           v_pcFI IN DATE,
           v_pcFF   IN DATE,
           v_vSuma  IN NUMBER
    )
    AS

    vcMLista SYS_REFCURSOR;

    BEGIN

     IF v_vSuma = 0 THEN
         BEGIN

               open vcMLista for

                    SELECT tablax.num_entrada ,
                      tablax.ejercicio ,
                      tablax.num_expediente ,
                      tablax.num_acuerdo ,
                      tablax.num_sentencia
                    FROM tablax
                    JOIN tablaz
                         ON tablaz.num_expediente = tablax.num_expediente
                            WHERE tablax.est_suma          = 0
                    AND ( EXISTS
                           (SELECT 1
                                 FROM tablay
                                 WHERE tablay.cve_usuario = v_vcUsr_actual
                                 AND tablay.cve_region    =  tablaz.cve_region
                                 AND tablay.cve_sala      = tablaz.cve_sala
                                 AND tablay.cve_mag       = tablaz.cve_mag
                                 AND tablay.cve_srio      = tablaz.cve_srio
                            ))
                            FOR UPDATE;
```

Posteriormente en SQL SERVER se utiliza una tabla temporal y se hace lo siguiente:

```
     update tablax 
     set notificado = 1,
     fec_notificado = getdate()
     from @crLista MLista
     where MLista.NEnt = tablax.num_entrada and
     MLista.NEje = tablax.ejercicio and tablax.est_suma = @vSuma

     update tablay set fmod =getdate()
        where ndoc in 
        (select distinct NExp from @crLista)
```

¿Como puedo hacer lo equivalente en PLSQL con un cursor ?
he intentado lo siguiente:

```
      OPEN crLista;
         FETCH crLista INTO reg;

         WHILE crLista%FOUND LOOP
           UPDATE actm_lista SET  
               notificado = 1,
               FEC_NOTIFICADO = sysdate
               WHERE CURRENT OF crLista;
         FETCH crLista INTO reg;
         END LOOP;

     OPEN crLista;
        FETCH crLista INTO reg;
         WHILE crLista%FOUND LOOP  
             UPDATE tablax
                 SET fmod = SYSDATE
             WHERE ne  IN
                   (SELECT DISTINCT reg.ne FROM crLista);
         FETCH crLista INTO reg;
     END LOOP;



     UPDATE tablay
            SET fmod = SYSDATE
            WHERE ndoc IN
            (SELECT DISTINCT ndoc FROM crLista) ;
```

Pero al intentar hacer el from crLista obtengo el error la tabla o vista no existe

Espero puedan apoyarme, gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola user34..., la pregunta no es muy clara. ¿Puedes explicar mejor lo que se supone que el código debe lograr? ¿En qué aspecto específico estás teniendo dificultad?

Comment: La duda concreta es la siguiente:

Comment: en SQL Server puedo hacer lo siguiente :         `update tablax 
             set notificado = 1,
             fec_notificado = getdate()
             from @crLista MLista
             where MLista.NEnt = tablax.num_entrada and
             MLista.NEje = tablax.ejercicio and tablax.est_suma = @vSuma`    Pero en PLSQL al hacer el from hacia un cursor obtengo el error: "La tabla o vista no existe"

Comment: Ejemplo:  `OPEN crLista;
    FETCH crLista INTO reg;
    WHILE crLista%FOUND LOOP  
        UPDATE genm_est_exp_usr
          SET fec_ult_notificacion = SYSDATE
              WHERE num_expediente    IN
                (SELECT DISTINCT reg.num_expediente FROM crLista);
              FETCH crLista INTO reg;
    END LOOP;`

Comment: Te sugiero de agregar los detalles adicionales directamente a la pregunta original. Puedes usar el enlace [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/50801/edit) para esto.